# UWP JavaScript APP: run win32 EXE with parameters

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

What is the best working way to call a win32 executable from JavaScript UWP app (Windows Anniversary update)

I have tried to configure the win32 via an AppService:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" StartPage="www\index.html">
    <uap:AppService Name="CommunicationService" />
</uap:Extension>

<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="mywin32app.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" />
```

Now I can launch it with `Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.launchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync()` from JavaScript, but how do I launch It with parameters?

Comment: Did you every find a way to do this? I agree with you, the Parameter groups are useless as you cant pass runtime args

Comment: @mikeysee: no I try the appservice aproach right now

Answer (score 1):

> but how do I launch It with parameters

There is a with-parameter version of this method that you can use: [FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher.launchfulltrustprocessforcurrentappasync.aspx).

And declear the parameters in appxmanifest file:

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="fulltrustprocess.exe"> 
      <desktop:FullTrustProcess> 
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/Sync"/> 
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters="/Other"/> 
      </desktop:FullTrustProcess> 
</desktop:Extension>
```

Comment: But it looks like the parameters could only be defined in the manifest, right? So how do I use dynamic parameters for the call?

Comment: Yes, the parameters could only be defined in the manifest and `GroupId` be passed as the argument to the method. I'm out of ideas of other options to pass the parameters.

Comment: Hm but this is useless. There should be a way do define the parameters during runtime.

Comment: You can define all parameters in appmanifest, and during runtime change the `GroupId` dynamically to decide which parameter to use.

Comment: Also you are welcomed to deliver Feature Request Feedback through Windows Feedback App to help us improve our work.

Comment: @Elvis Xia - MSFT, how could I determine that parameter in win 32 application.???

Answer (score 0):

The provided mechanism for passing parameters doesn't seem to allow you to do them dynamically at the moment, which is not ideal. You can only pass through hard-coded parameters to your process. I suggest using an App Service extension in your UWP app to make data available to your full trust process. The process is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend#provide-services-to-other-apps).

Do it this way:

Launch full trust process. Add a parameter to indicate that it is launched from UWP.

In your full trust process, check if the parameter was passed in, and call back to the UWP process' app service task to get the data you would otherwise pass in as a parameter.